# Extracting a value from an object from a dapper query in backend

Tags: c#, object

I am getting an array of objects(oMessageData) from my backend like this:

```
foreach(var l in oMessageData)
{
                                        
     Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l));
}
```

and one of the result is:

```
{some data}
{some data}
{some data}
{some data}
{"SetId":"1","ValueType":"FT","ObservationIdentifier":"COVID-19 qRT-PCR","ObservationValue":"Not Detected","ObservationResultStatus":"F","DateAndTimeOfObservation":"2022-02-02T22:53:26.28"}
{some data}
```

I want to extract `DateAndTimeOfObservation` , but whenn I do  `var date = oMessageData[4].['DateAndTimeOfObservation']`, it says `Identifier expected`.
I also couldn't get it with :
`oMessageData[4].values[5]`.

How do I extract that value?

This is the structure of 0MessageData[4]:
[oMessageData[4]](https://ibb.co/R3ZrnNJ)

Edit: I am getting this data from dapper query and the first element in object is DapperRow,like this:

```
{{DapperRow, SetId = '1', ValueType = 'FT', ObservationIdentifier = 'COVID-19 qRT-PCR', ObservationValue = 'Not Detected', ObservationResultStatus = 'F', DateAndTimeOfObservation = '02-02-2022 22:53:26'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you get a dicionary object. This means that the target record is not lookable by an index, like in an array, but by a key.

On the screenshot the Values property is expanded. Each of these entries is assigned to a key from the Keys property. With this key you can access the target entry.

For more details on dictionaries, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried looking up with tryGetValue() also, but no success. Also , I guess I have to deserialize before getting getting the value but it says unexpected symbol found at 1st position.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer was given based on my *wrong* impression that `oMessageData` is the collection of the serialized objects. That is not the case, as can be seen in the question post.)

---

[As Gabriel is pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284435/extracting-a-value-from-an-object-in-an-array-from-backend#answer-71284662), the variable displayed in the screenshot seems to be of a dictionary type. I suspect that if you expand the `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>.Keys` line (the line above the first expanded line in your screenshot), you will see `"DateAndTimeOfObservation"` being listed as one of the dictionary keys.

You claim that the screenshot displays the structure of `oMessageData[4]`; in that case, you should get the desired value by setting `date` as follows:

```
var date = oMessageData[4]["DateAndTimeOfObservation"];
```

Or, in a more descriptive manner; displaying more clearly how you obtain the value for a given `key` in a `dictionary`:

```
var dictionary = oMessageData[4];
var key = "DateAndTimeOfObservation";
var date = dictionary[key];
```

Comment: Astrid , I already tried this and it says , can't apply indexing to object.
I also made an edit. Can you please take a look at it.

Comment: @sapter Then you probably need to cast it to a `Dictionary<string, string>` (or possibly other key/value types) first; something similar to `((Dictionary<string, string>)oMessageData[4])["DateAndTimeOfObservation"]`? (Preferrably, split into several variables.) If that works, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was able to get the value by first serializing and then deserializing it . Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @sapter Right, I see now that I misread your question! Sorry about that. I thought you had saved the _output_ of your serializations in `oMessageData`, but `oMessageData` is of course the collection whose items you are serializing. My bad. Glad you figured it out!